# calculate quantity and total specified price

Tags: php, html, css

I'm doing a small exercise of buying items, I have the idea of ​​how to make it works, however, I cannot find the key to give me the result of the total price of the purchased product. I'm work it in PHP. Basically what I want to do is, if you buy 5 pens, then multiply those 0.50 what cost the pens x 5 and show me the total to pay. (Forget the $ book variable at the end, because even if I multiply the total number of books purchased, I can't figure out how to do it as for the rest of the products).

```css
session_start();
$_SESSION["nombre"] = "Comprador";
echo "<p><b><u>Bienvenido $_SESSION[nombre]</u></b></p>";

//PRECIOS DE LOS ARTICULOS
$books = 1.50;
$pen = 0.50;
$stapler = 3.00;
$cardboard = 0.90;
$File = 0.20;
$pencil = 0.10;
$Kit = 5.50;

//CHOOSE THE PRODUCT
if(isset($_SESSION['nombre'])==true) 
{
    if($_POST['articulo']==1)
    {
        echo "You will buy: book";
    }

    elseif($_POST['articulo']==2)
    {
        echo "You will buy: pen";
    }

    elseif($_POST['articulo']==3)
    {
        echo "You will buy: stapler";
    }

    elseif($_POST['articulo']==4)
    {
        echo "You will buy: cardboard";
    }

    elseif($_POST['articulo']==5)
    {
        echo "You will buy: File";
    }

    elseif($_POST['articulo']==6)
    {
        echo "You will buy: Pencil";
    }

    elseif($_POST['articulo']==7)
    {
        echo "You will buy: Kit";
    }

    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: Your cart is empty :(";
    }

    //HOW MANY?
      if(isset($_POST['number']))
      {
        if(!empty($_POST['number']))
        {
            echo "<br/>";
            $number=$_POST['number'];
            echo "Cantidad a comprar: " . $number;
        }

        else
        {
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "Fail: You must choose how many will buy";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<a href='inicio.php'> Cancelar </a>";
        }
      }
}

//PAY

if (isset($_POST['articulo']) && isset($_POST['number']))
{
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "You have to pay: " . $number * $book . " €.";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a href='pedidos.php'> Pay it </a>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a href='inicio.php'> Volver </a>";
}


//FAIL SEASSON
else
{
    echo "no se ha iniciado la sesión";
}

    ?>
```

```html
<h1>WELLCOME!</h1>

<form id="inicio" method="post" action="carrito.php">
    <p>
        <select name="articulo">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">Books - 1.50€</option> 
            <option value="2">Pens - 0.50€</option> 
            <option value="3">stapler - 3.00€</option>
            <option value="4">Cardboard - 0.90€</option> 
            <option value="5">File - 0.20€</option> 
            <option value="6">Pencil - 0.10€</option>
            <option value="7">Kit - 5.00€</option>
         </select>
    </p>
    
    <p>
        <label for="nombre">How many do you want to buy?</label>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="number" name="number" id="number">
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Añadir al carrito">
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to approach allowing the user to build up a shopping cart full of items and then calculating the price, but I believe that is out of scope of this question.

In terms of the single scenario you have shown above. Ie user purchases X number of one single item. Then one small adaption to your code would be to define a $total variable, set to zero at the beginning of file.

Then within your conditional if blocks, for example where it equals 2 'pens'. Multiply value of pens by number of items and add that to your total. Then display total.

If you want to allow for adding other items, then you could store the first selection (i.e. 5 pens) to an array, then save the array as a session variable. Then in each subsequent load of page, read the array and add all items to $total variable.